# C# Point3DCollection select point by min or max coordinate

Tags: c#, linq, 3d, coordinates, point

I have Point3DCollection of hundreds of points like
Point3D(2, 5, 8), 
Point3D(8, 6, 9), 
Point3D(5, 8, 12)... 
and I need to get coordinates of those which have lowest and highest X. I know how to find lowest value (using LINQ Min), but I don't know, how to find lowest value and get Y and Z of it.
Can you please help me?

Comment: You can use the `OrderBy `on `X` which will sort the collection for lowest to highest for `X`. Now First should give the Min and Last should give you the Max. With this approach you can also select top(2 or 3 or .....) and last (2 or 3. or....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose your `Point3DCollection` is list of `Point3D` class's object. and your `Point3D` class looks like this.

```
public class Point3D
{
  public int X;
  public int Y;
  public int Z;

  public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
  {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
  }
}
```

your desired `Linq` will be

for lowest X

```
Point3D p = Point3DCollection.OrderBy(x => x.X).FirstOrDefault();
```

for highest x

```
if(Point3DCollection.Count > 0)
   Point3D p = Point3DCollection.OrderBy(x => x.X).Last();
```

you should better check of emptiness of `Point3DCollection` first.

[here is working sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PScEgy)